# Tkinter buttons in same line but with a scrolledtext for 2 columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm doing on a GUI using tkinter of python3. 
For a frame, i wanna the result is like this:
[image]
but when i tried with this code:

```
master.title("Homepage")
master.title("Window to check information")
master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (850, 800, (master.winfo_screenwidth() - 850) / 2, 0))

self.information = tkst.ScrolledText(self, wrap=tk.WORD, height=20, width=100)
self.btn1 = tk.Button(self, text='Cours', height=3, width=40)
self.btn2 = tk.Button(self, text='Absences',  height=3, width=40)
self.btn3 = tk.Button(self, text='Notes',  height=3, width=40)
self.btn4 = tk.Button(self, text='Return',  height=3, width=40)

self.information.config(font=font.Font(size=15))
self.information.configure(background='#C0C0C0')

self.btn2.config(font=font.Font(size=12))
self.btn3.config(font=font.Font(size=12))
self.btn1.config(font=font.Font(size=12))
self.btn4.config(font=font.Font(size=12))

self.information.grid(row=0,column=0)
self.btn1.grid(row=1,column=0)
self.btn2.grid(row=1,column=1)
self.btn3.grid(row=2,column=0)
self.btn4.grid(row=2,column=1)
```

i found the GUI is like :
[image]

Can someone help me how can i write the code of grid or pack to realise the first picture? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make the `ScrolledText` span both columns, you need to use the `columnspan` option in grid:

```
self.information.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The same effect can also be achieved with the `pack` method which I find to be more preferable as it handles windows expanding better than the grid system.

See below for a mock-up of how this can be achieved:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frametop = Frame(root)
framebottom = Frame(root)
frameleft = Frame(framebottom)
frameright = Frame(framebottom)

text = Text(frametop)
scroll = Scrollbar(frametop, command=text.yview)
btn1 = Button(frameleft, text="Course")
btn2 = Button(frameleft, text="Abscences")
btn3 = Button(frameright, text="Notes")
btn4 = Button(frameright, text="Return")

text['yscrollcommand'] = scroll.set

frametop.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
framebottom.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
frameleft.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
frameright.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

text.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, padx=5, pady=5, expand=1)
scroll.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, padx=5, pady=5, expand=1)
btn1.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, padx=5, pady=5, expand=1)
btn2.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, padx=5, pady=5, expand=1)
btn3.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, padx=5, pady=5, expand=1)
btn4.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, padx=5, pady=5, expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```

This creates four frames and packs the items into their specified places with padding between them:

[image]

Expanding or shrinking the window (within reason, shrinking too much causes Tkinter to start hiding items) will cause the items to automatically move and change size.